# Add-in enabled in outlook and open .msg file for second time it give us an error

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

#### Working fine when my add-in is disabled on Outlook:

**Outlook** allows me to open `.msg` file.

---

#### Failed when my add-in enabled on Outlook:

**Outlook** allows me to open `.msg` file once, but when I closed that message window and tried to open the same `.msg` file again then it shown me an error.

`We can't open MSG_FILE_LOCATION. It's possible the file is already open, or you don't have permission to open it. To check your permissions, right-click the file folder, then click property.`

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What your addin is for? Maybe the file actually stays open in your addin when you close it in Outlook

Comment: my addin is for creating a meeting and appointment invite.

Comment: does it work with these .msg files somehow?